# Jenkins job with "Active choices plugin" loads really slow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, cloudbees

Hello we are using "active choices plug-in" (v2.6.3) in 1 of our jenkins controller, and 1 job which has 4 choice parameters along with 3 "Active Choices Reactive Parameter" configured, when we use jenkins console to build with parameter page takes as long as 22 seconds to load the page with all the choices and parameters.
so far we have checked underlying NAS for slowness , different versions of this plugin , dependent "script security" plugin and an advisory by [cloudbees](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/troubleshooting-guides/the-build-with-parameters-screen-loads-slowly) as well. Issue still persists..
Is there any way to mitigate this?

Answer (score -1):

Without any code and configuration it's hard to tell whats the reason behind it.
I guess it's mostly fault of your scripts inside parameters not a plugin itself.
If you have big instance and script which is scanning multiple times all objects inside it happens.

Please report this in Jenkins Jira with all logs and useful materials.